# How to make an SMTP Server in Python to send email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

I was looking around, but I couldn't find a really definite way to setup an SMTP server in Python that can just send messages. I saw inbox.py, but there was a lack of documentation and I couldn't figure out how it works. I don't need to save emails to files, all I need is the ability to send them.

Thanks for any recommendations!

Comment: If you're just sending them to somewhere else, that's not a server, that's a client.  python has a built-in module for that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: This is far too vague and broad.